# Why are PHPExcel files broken when saving remotely?

Tags: php, phpexcel

I'm having a weird issue with [PHPExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/) saving files remotely.

**This is the code I use for browser download:**

```
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="filename.xls"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
```

Unfortunately, every file I download this way cannot be open by neither of [LibreOffice](http://www.libreoffice.org/) and [Microsoft Office](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/).

**BUT if I replace all those lines with this single line:**

```
$objWriter->save(str_replace('.php', '.xls', __FILE__));
```

The file can be opened and all data/formatting is perfect. The only problem is that it saves it on the server, right next to the controller that generates it.

What could cause this and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

when you save it 'remotely', what extension does the file has? if it is PHP, you might want to try to change its extension to xls manually and see if it works

Comment: The extension is fine, it saves just like it should, it's just that when I try to open the file, it asks for encoding and stuff.

Comment: Soooo... nobody knows? Because I have absolutely no idea why this is happening... Could it have something to do with .htaccess?